# Node-run-cmd Error after electron application is packaged

Tags: javascript, node.js, runtime-error, electron, packaging

So I'm having a issue when after I package an electron application this node function is unable to run, but in development the function works perfectly well.
 This is the error that is supplied when the command is called like this:

```
function run(){
try{
    exc.compileExec();
}catch(e){
    alert(e);
}
```

}

Error: [cannot find module 'node-run-cmd'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqFXO.png)

```
exports.compileExec = function(){
var {remote} = require('electron');    
const ref = remote.require("./main.js");
var nrc = require('node-run-cmd');
var commands = [
    'file.exe'
];

var options = { cwd:  'Compiler' };
nrc.run(commands, options).then(function(){ ref.endResults(); });};
```

Comment: Is there anyway to bump this question to a more informed state?

Answer (score 0):

npm i node-run-cmd

Install  again

Comment: Did the install its also referenced in the package.json file as well, packaged the program again and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Please check `package.json` file is `node-run-cmd` package is included or nor and if not then add `node-run-cmd` package and run `npm i`. you need to `--save` when installing package to add in `package.json` like `npm install --save node-run-cmd`.

Comment: Did the install and reinstalled it as you suggested its also referenced in the package.json file as well. Packaged the program again to an exe and it gives the same error. Edit:`  "dependencies": {
    "arrive": "^2.4.1",
    "electron-debug": "^1.5.0",
    "electron-packager": "^12.0.0",
    "node-run-cmd": "^1.0.1"
  }`

Comment: Can you please check node-run-cmd folder is available in node_modules folder and check files are same as development environment files?

Comment: The node-run-cmd folder is in the node_modules folder , not sure what you mean by the development environment files. Also as stated previously the program works when in development when running it via node start in cmd. I'm only receiving this error when the program is packaged. edit `,
    "node-run-cmd": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/node-run-cmd/-/node-run-cmd-1.0.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-F1XBJiS9/5INj0UkLWZC4hSj1AA="
    },` this is found in the app.asar file when packaged